# Нужно ли брать в кавычки слова на английском?

Tags: пунктуация

Но при определенной «одежке» можно не пройти и «face control», а тогда до ума (до продукции) и дело не дойдет.

В интернете встречала информацию, что слова, написанные на латинице, не кавычатся, но ведь здесь face control употребляется в переносном значении. Распространяется ли это правило и на слова на английском языке?

Answer (score 3):

---

### Ответ справочной службы русского языка

---

Прежде всего отметим, что в справочниках по правописанию нет рекомендаций по орфографическому оформлению названий, написанных латиницей.

По мнению председателя Орфографической комиссии РАН д. ф. н., проф. В. В. Лопатина, названия литературных и научных произведений, произведений искусства, даже написанные латиницей, целесообразно заключать в кавычки (здесь на употребление данного выделительного знака влияет семантика наименования: в большинстве случаев написанные латиницей названия в кавычки не заключаются). Корректно: собравшиеся исполнили песню «Strangers in the night». В любом случае употребление кавычек здесь ошибкой быть не может.

***Ответ справки.***

Ни в одном из современных справочных пособий по правописанию нет рекомендаций по употреблению кавычек в названиях, написанных латиницей. Рекомендации, приводимые ниже, сформулированы на основе наблюдений над современной письменной речью.
<...>
Отсутствие кавычек в оформленных латиницей названиях может быть рекомендовано по отношению ко всем употребляемым в русских текстах группам наименований. В их числе:
<...>
- названия спортивных обществ, музыкальных коллективов, например: группы Lordi, Rammstein, Bee Gees, Rolling Stones, футбольный клуб PSV Eindhoven.
<...>
Однако при стечении в тексте двух (и более) наименований, написанных латиницей, предпочтительно употребление кавычек для предупреждения неверного понимания текста читателем. Например: новая серия микроволновых печей фирмы Samsung «Aqua».

Спорным является вопрос о целесообразности употребления кавычек в названиях литературных и научных произведений, произведений искусства, документов, периодических изданий и т. п. <...> Ввиду семантики данных названий заключение их в кавычки может быть предпочтительно. Окончательное решение о постановке кавычек в таких случаях принимает автор текста.

Comment: Да, но здесь речь идет о названиях, а у меня это просто выражение, да еще и в переносном значении.

Comment: Почему же, это тоже название. Фейс-контроль - это своего рода процедура. Т.е. название процедуры. Кстати, а почему вы пишите латиницей? Название в словарях зафиксировано: Фейс-контроль

Comment: Так ведь это не я пишу. Автор захотел написать так.

Comment: Аленка, кавычки служат выделительным знаком в тексте. А написание латиницей уже выделено, зачем еще выделять?! Если бы написание латиницей представляло бы собой какое-то необычное выражение, кавычки могли бы еще быть оправданы. В данном случае выражение достаточно известно и фиксируется словарями, причин для постановки кавычек нет. Название в кавычках в данном случае может быть воспринято в ином смысле.